# How to limit the number of characters in laravel to convert to URL

Tags: laravel, url, character

I am using the google geocoding API to get latitude and longitude of addresses, the problem is that it is for Japanese users, which have "special" characters and when I use the service, the URL is too long

that results in a ZERO_RESULTS response

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

instead, if I delete some characters, I do get the results I want, what I'm looking for is to achieve that, for example

```
$customerAddress = "日本 〒462-0825 愛知県 名古屋市北区 大曽根３丁目 １３-２V-Handsビル 1F"
```

do not exceed the number of characters allowed by the URL, which in the end I end up putting together like this

```
$geocodingUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$customerAddress&key=$apiKey";
```

it doesn't matter if i remove characters from the end, but I need the address to not be SO specific so it can fit in the url

[with this tool](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview), we can verify what I say when placing the example address, we receive ZERO_RESULTS until we delete part of the text

how could I do it?

[here is more documentation of the construction of the URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/web-service-best-practices#BuildingURLs)

[URL encode to verify that it is too long by placing Japanese characters](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Laravel `Str` helper to limit your string like this:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$rawCustomerAddress = "a very long address";
$maxAddressLength = 200;

$customerAddress = Str::limit($rawCustomerAddress, $maxAddressLength);

$geocodingUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$customerAddress&key=$apiKey";
```

More details [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-str-limit)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I guess this will cut the apiKey and not the address, in any case I would have to apply it in $customerAddress, not in the URL

Comment: You're right. It's should be better to limit the `$customerAddress`.
I'll edit my answer.

Comment: the problem is that Japanese characters, when converted to URL, occupy many more characters, when using Str::limit() the characters are being taken into account as a string and not as a URL, which causes problems to continue build the URL

look at this page and put the example address  `日本 〒462-0825 愛知県 名古屋市北区 大曽根３丁目 １３-２V-Handsビル 1F`

https://www.url-encode-decode.com/

Comment: [As per the Google documentation you provided](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/web-service-best-practices#BuildingURLs), you need to utf8 encode your japanese string so that it only uses the valid ASCII characters Google wants.